# How to create different menu page for each page

Tags: ionic4

I am using Ionic 4, I want to do different menu content in different page. I have add menuId inside my code, but I only get the second page menu. My first page menu is missing.

Comment: you can use a menu controller to open and close the desired menu

Answer (score 2):

I think you should build 1 menu and then just populate its page list depending on the page being visited.

So your code would look something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.page.scss'],
})
export class MenuPage implements OnInit {
  selectedPath = '';

  pages = getPages();

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      if (event && event.url) {
        this.selectedPath = event.url;
      }
    });
  }

  getPages() : any[] {

   if (this.router.url === '/page1') { 
       return [
    {
      title: 'First Page with Tabs',
      url: '/menu/first'
    },
    {
      title: 'Second Page blank',
      url: '/menu/second'
    }
  ];
}

   if (this.router.url === '/page2') { 
     return [
    {
      title: 'First Page with Tabs',
      url: '/menu/first'
    },
    {
      title: 'Second Page blank',
      url: '/menu/second'
    }
  ];
}
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

And then display it like this:

```
<ion-split-pane>
  <ion-menu contentId="content">

    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of pages">
          <ion-item [routerLink]="p.url" routerDirection="root" [class.active-item]="selectedPath.startsWith(p.url)">
            <ion-label>
              {{ p.title }}
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>

        <ion-item tappable routerLink="/login" routerDirection="root">
          <ion-icon name="log-out" slot="start"></ion-icon>
          Logout
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

  </ion-menu>

  <ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>

</ion-split-pane>
```

Full tutorial about setting up a menu like this is available here:

[How to Combine Ionic 4 Tabs and Side Menu Navigation [v4] - Ionic AcademyIonic Academy](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-4-tabs-side-menu/)

Although the code I used as an example above for get `getPages()` is the bit you would write yourself.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I want to do like menu 1 is for first page, menu 2 for page 2. Different menu have different content. I have using menuId but it did not work for both menu

Comment: my answer describes how to do that. You don't use multiple menu's and set id's, you make two sets of page lists and then bind them. Which bit do you need more explanation for? I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: so, I need to generate 3 page? First for menu 1, Second for menu 2, Last for combine the menu?

Comment: Im having trouble getting a grasp on what level of experience you are at. I would recommend follow the tutorial I linked to so that you get an idea for how you can populate a menu by passing an array to it. Once you have understood that then take another look at my answer. My modification to the tutorial `getPages()` demos a way that instead of just supplying one array, it sets up two and returns a different list of pages depending on the page.